# How to detect scroll end on flutter webview?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently building an application using flutter with webview for mobile. how to detect scroll when it reaches the end of line of a website page in webview?

Comment: You'll need some JavaScript, and know how to operate a JavaScript Channel between your app and the WebView. And each WebView plugin has it's own JavaScript Channel operating method.
On your website, it needs to declare a custom function after `document.onLoad` and begin a communication channel with the Flutter app. This [link](https://thewebdev.info/2021/06/27/how-to-detect-scroll-end-with-javascript/) could help with the scroll event detection on JavaScript side.
I rather suggest you recreate a mobile version of that website page and use Flutter exclusive APIs to solve your requirement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding this script on flutter side

```
WebView(
    initialUrl: "http://url.com/tos",
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    javascriptChannels: [
    JavascriptChannel(
        name: 'FLUTTER_CHANNEL',
        onMessageReceived: (message) {
            if (message.message.toString() ==
                "end of scroll") {
                setState((){ 
                    enableAgreeButton = true; 
                });
            }
        })
    ].toSet(),
    gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
    debuggingEnabled: true,
)
```

and this on js side

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    window.FLUTTER_CHANNEL.postMessage('end of scroll');
    }
};
</script>
```

thanks to nsNeruno and Starscream for the insight

Comment: It works fine for iOS and most Android devices, but the listener on flutter side does not listen on a few Android 10 devices and all Android 13 devices.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, so I import syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer. You can set controller on this viewer and use listener.

It can be done through Javascript with webview, but it is a little bit complicated.

Answer (score 1):

With webview_flutter (4.2.1) you add javascript channel to webview controller and listen to message received on it. From webview you can send scroll progress messages to this channel. Inside onMessageReceived you can get progress:

```js
Future<void> fetchArticle() async {
    late final PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams params;
    params = const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams();

    final WebViewController controller =
        WebViewController.fromPlatformCreationParams(params);

    controller
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..addJavaScriptChannel(
        'ARTICLE_SCROLL_CHANNEL',
        onMessageReceived: (progress) {
          setState(() {
            position = double.parse(progress.message) / 100;
          });
        },
      )
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            _controller.runJavaScript(
              '''
              window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
                progress = (this.scrollY / ( document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight ) ) * 100;
                window.ARTICLE_SCROLL_CHANNEL.postMessage(progress);
              });
              ''',
            );
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'));

    _controller = controller;
  }
```